# Every irreducible representation of $G_2$ appears in some tensor power of the standard representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

In the Book "Representation Theory" by Fulton and Harris, this fact ist stated on page 353 after looking at the weight diagrams of the complex Lie-Algebra $G_2$. The authors deduce that with $V=\Gamma_{1,0} $ being the 7-dimensional standard representation of $G_2$ with heighest weight $\omega_1 =2 \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$: $\Lambda V = \Gamma_{0,1} \oplus V$, with $\Gamma_{0,1}$ being the adjoint representation with highest weight $\omega_2 =3 \alpha _1 + 2 \alpha _2$. They then state the following, which I don't quite see:

"In particular, since the adjoint representation $\Gamma_{0,1}$ of $G_2$ is contained in $\Lambda V$, and the irreducible representation $\Gamma_{a,b}$ with highest weight $a\omega_1 + b\omega_2$ is contained in the tensor product $Sym^a V \otimes Sym^b \Gamma_{0,1}$, we see that every irreducible representation of $G_2$ appears in some tensor power $V^{\otimes m}$ of the standard representation."

It would be nice if someone could shed some light on this for me. Note that I dont have the full book here, I could only copy what chapters I thought I needed, so basically only the chapter about the representations of $G_2$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\Gamma_{0,1}$ is contained in $\Lambda^2V\subset V\otimes V$, you see that $\Gamma_{a,b}\subset Sym^a V\otimes Sym^b \Gamma_{0,1}\subset \otimes^a V\otimes \otimes^b(\otimes^2 V)\subset\otimes^{a+2b}V$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, the only thing not yet clear to me is the first inclusion you state: $\Gamma_{a,b} \subset Sym^a V \otimes Sym^b \Gamma_{0,1}.$ How do you see that?

Comment: This is a classical observation, which is the basis for all case-by-case proofs of existence of representations. If $v_0\in V$ and $w_0\in\Gamma_{0,1}$ are highest weight vectors, then you look at the vector $(v_0\vee\dots\vee v_0)\otimes (w_0\vee\dots\vee w_0)\in Sym^aV\otimes Sym^b\Gamma_{0,1}$. A simple direct computation shows that this is a highest weight vector and its weight is $a$ times the weight of $v_0$ plus $b$ times the weight of $w_0$. Then there is a general theorem saying that such a vector generates an irreducible subrepresentation isomorphic to $\Gamma_{a,b}$.